# How do I run a process from vim that runs in a separate pane, while I continue to look at code?

Tags: shell, vim, tmux

I got tmux installed, and I can run make and it builds in a pane down, and I can continue to look at code. I would also like to run scripts(tests) and they should run while I see the results of the tests in another pane, while I look at code. How can I do that?

Comment: Just to double check, you want a workflow where you are using Vim and you want to perform a command that will open another tmux window with a particular process but still have your Vim code in focus?

Comment: You should take a look at Tim Pope's vim-dispatch plugin (https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) it probably does exactly what you want.

Comment: I do this just by opening another terminal window and arranging them side-by-side. You're asking about using a single terminal window to split into two tmux sessions?

Comment: @Gordonium: Yes. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JulienGrenier: I do have vim-dispatch, but doesn't it only support compiling?

Comment: @Kache: I'm looking for the latter, having a single terminal window, but 2 panes/tabs.

Comment: @JulienGrenier: I just discovered that what I said is wrong. You are right. vim-dispatch does support dispatching any process. It works, and I love it. Thanks a lot!